# R padding 0's inside a string

Tags: regex, string, r

I have the following data

```
GT-BU7867-09
GT-BU6523-113
GT-BU6452-1
GT-BU8921-12
```

How do I use R to make the numbers after the hyphen to pad leading zeros so it will have three digits? The resulting format should look like this:

```
GT-BU7867-009
GT-BU6523-113
GT-BU6452-001
GT-BU8921-012
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Base solution:

```
sapply(strsplit(x,"-"), function(x)
    paste(x[1], x[2], sprintf("%03d",as.numeric(x[3])), sep="-")
)
```

Result:

```
[1] "GT-BU7867-009" "GT-BU6523-113" "GT-BU6452-001" "GT-BU8921-012"
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `stringr` and `str_pad` and `strsplit`

```
library(stringr)
    x <- readLines(textConnection('GT-BU7867-09
GT-BU6523-113
GT-BU6452-1
GT-BU8921-12'))

unlist(lapply(strsplit(x,'-'),
       function(x){
         x[3] <- str_pad(x[3], width = 3, side = 'left', pad = '0')
         paste0(x, collapse = '-')}))

[1] "GT-BU7867-009" "GT-BU6523-113" "GT-BU6452-001"
[4] "GT-BU8921-012"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another version using `str_pad` and `str_extract` from package `stringr`

```
library(stringr)   
x <- gsub("[[:digit:]]+$", str_pad(str_extract(x, "[[:digit:]]+$"), 3, pad = "0"), x)
```

i.e. extract the trailing numbers of x, pad them to 3 with 0s, then substitute these for the original trailing numbers.