# R padding 0's inside a string after the hypen

Tags: r, regex, string

I have the following data

```
GT_BUC-01_BUCST-19
ADT_BURC-1_BUCST-09
BT_BUDDC-1_BUDSCST-29
CAST_BUC-31_BUCST-9
CAST_BUC-1_BUCST-9
```

How do I use R to make the numbers after both hyphens to pad leading zeros so it will have Two digits? The resulting format should look like this:

```
GT_BUC-01_BUCST-19
ADT_BURC-01_BUCST-09
BT_BUDDC-01_BUDSCST-29
CAST_BUC-31_BUCST-09
CAST_BUC-01_BUCST-09
```

Comment: I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/13507007/15180205 solution but I am not able to figure out how to change it for my problem and what exactly it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `gsub` as follows:

```
x <- gsub("-(\\d)(?!\\d)", "-0\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
x

[1] "GT_BUC-01_BUCST-19"     "ADT_BURC-01_BUCST-09"   "BT_BUDDC-01_BUDSCST-29"
[4] "CAST_BUC-31_BUCST-09"   "CAST_BUC-01_BUCST-09"
```

**Data:**

```
x <- c("GT_BUC-01_BUCST-19",
       "ADT_BURC-1_BUCST-09",
       "BT_BUDDC-1_BUDSCST-29",
       "CAST_BUC-31_BUCST-9",
       "CAST_BUC-1_BUCST-9")
```

The regex pattern used here matches dash followed by a single number only.  In this case, we then replace by prepending a zero to this single number.

Comment: If I had "BUC6-01" sting and I want this result "BUC06-01" How would we implement it?

Comment: Generally: `gsub("(?<!\\d)(\\d)(?!\\d)", "0\\1", x)` should work.

Comment: Happy to help you!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `stringr::str_replace_all`

```
x <- c('GT_BUC-01_BUCST-19', 'ADT_BURC-1_BUCST-09', 
       'BT_BUDDC-1_BUDSCST-29', 'CAST_BUC-31_BUCST-9', 'CAST_BUC-1_BUCST-9')

stringr::str_replace_all(x, '\\d+', function(m) sprintf('%02s', m))

#[1] "GT_BUC-01_BUCST-19"     "ADT_BURC-01_BUCST-09"  
#[3] "BT_BUDDC-01_BUDSCST-29" "CAST_BUC-31_BUCST-09"  
#[5] "CAST_BUC-01_BUCST-09"
```